# Delete headers from Angular.js $http request

Tags: angularjs, http, http-headers

I want to delete some `$http` request header fields from one specific request (it means not on the `$httpProvider` level). These fields are:

- Cache-Control
- If-Modified-Since
- Referer
- X-Requested-With

How to do this in a single request? I tried to use `transformRequest` parameter, but didn't find enough information to make it work. Such a [CoffeeScript] code:

```
$scope.logout = ->
  $http({
    method: 'GET'
    url: '/api/logout'
    headers: { 'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8' }
    transformRequest: (data, headersGetter) ->
      console.log data
      console.log headersGetter
      data
  }).success ->
    $location.path('editor')
```

shows that `data` is `undefined`, headersGetter is `function (c){a||(a=Nb(b));return c?a[y(c)]||null:a}` (which says to me absolutely nothing), and I didn't understand what to return from the transformRequest function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. If you use the unminified version of Angular, you'll get nicer backtraces when an exception happens, and you'll have an easier time introspecting the angular code. I personally recommend it while developing. Here's what `headersGetter` actually looks like:

   ```
   function (name) {
       if (!headersObj) headersObj =  parseHeaders(headers);

       if (name) {
         return headersObj[lowercase(name)] || null;
       }

       return headersObj;
     }
   ```

   The `data` argument to your transformer will be undefined unless you’re POSTing some data.
2. The `headersGetter` function takes an optional argument `name`, if you want to get a single header, but you omit the argument to set a header:

   ```
   headersGetter()['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache';
   headersGetter()['X-Requested-With'] = '';
   ```

   The return value from your transformer should be the value of `data` you want to use.
3. You [can’t change the `Referer` header](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-setrequestheader%28%29-method) from XHR.